# Register type library during installation

Tags: visual-studio, com, automation, installation, typelib

I have added an automation interface to an application I wrote. The type library is stored as a resource in the application, and on startup, the application calls `RegisterTypeLib` to register the type library automatically.

I just discovered that this call to `RegisterTypeLib` only works during development, where the application is launched from Visual Studio, because Visual Studio is running as administrator, and the application inherits this. When running the debug build from the command line, or when running the application as installed by the installer, the application is not running as administrator, and the call to `RegisterTypeLib` fails.

So I suppose I should register the type library during installation (which would also have the nice side effect of making the automation interface available without having to run the application first). The installer is a Windows Installer project in Visual Studio.

Is it possible to do achieve the effect of `RegisterTypeLib` during installation (and if yes, how)? When the installer solution is open, Visual Studio shows an editor called "Registry" wher one can add keys to the registry, but there's no way I can add each key separately - I need to somehow add the entire type library with a single call, like `RegisterTypeLib` does.

EDIT: After manuell's hint and some research of my own, the question boils down to this:
I need to call `MyApp /RegServer` from the installer (which will also create other required registry keys that aren't created by `RegisterTypeLib`); how exactly does one do this? I added an "Install" custom action in the Visual Studio installer solution, but haven't yet found out how to trigger it.

Comment: It is not very clear why you need to register it. If required then you also always have to write additional registry keys beyond the ones required for the type library, like HKCR\{progid}, HKCR\Interface and HKCR\CLSID. The entries added by RegisterTypeLib are just a minor addition.  Use SysInternal's ProcMon to get insight in what RegisterTypeLib writes.  And consider registering everything in HKCU instead of HKLM so you don't need admin rights.  RegisterTypeLibForUser now becomes useful.

Answer (score 1):

The usal way is to let the installer launch the application with the command line arguments  /regserver or /unregserver. If you use a Framework (MFC/ATL), the handling of all the registration (unregistration) steps are done automatically.

If you want to do all by your self, check the arguments to "main", and call RegisterTypeLib. The Windows installer should launch your EXE with /regserver, if it knows that's a com server.